# DateTimpicker not showing properly in jquery ui layout

Tags: css, eonasdan-datetimepicker, jquery-ui-layout

How can I make the datetimepicker work properly in the jquery ui layout. the datetimepicker is not showing when I click on the textfield it is behind in the south pane.

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/pv35uptc/4/)

```
<div class="ui-layout-north">North</div>
<div class="ui-layout-south">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


$(function(){
 $('body').layout({ applyDemoStyles: true });
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`moment.js` was missing in your code.
I have changed it & now its working fine. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pv35uptc/5/) is the updated fiddle.

```
$(function(){
 $('body').layout({ applyDemoStyles: true });
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

You will have to update your code to display datetimepicker properly.
You can refer https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/ for more formatting.

Comment: but the datepicker did not show properly ,it is behind in the southe pane

Comment: You will have to add necessary css rules to display it as you want. I just fixed the error related to not displaying datetimepicker. Do you need help in fixing CSS as well?

Comment: yes need help in fixing css,I want to show properly the datetimpicker .what rule of css should be added

Comment: You can force your daterangepicker to open always on bottom-left instead of auto arranging itself. Use following code.
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({widgetPositioning : { vertical : 'bottom', horizontal : 'left' },

will this help you?

Comment: Not good to see because it will create vertical scrollbar in the shouthpane due to the datetimepicker...I tried vertical top but still behind the shouth pane.